# how to set title in toolbar?

Tags: android, toolbar, android-titlebar

Seems pretty simple question, but could't find any answer.
How to change the toolbar title.

The toolbar is created by AppCompat Activity,not a custom created one.
It has the app name as default.I would like to change its Name corresponding to the action the activity performs.

Note : I can change custom toolbar title using the below code,so please i am not looking for that.

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("My Title");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set **default** `Toolbar` title as following:

```
YourActivity.this.setTitle("Your Title");
```

For *fragment*:

```
getActivity().setTitle("Your Title");
```

Answer (score 2):

getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title")

Answer (score 0):

Set `ActionBar` title based on your need

```
ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
ab.setTitle("My Title");
```